# How do I specify icons to use for the items in the navigation drawer?

Tags: android

Based on this [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui), I've added a navigation drawer to my app. Opening the navigation looks like this.

[image: screenshot]

What's with the grey squares where I'd like to use icons on the left there?

My nav graph XML looks like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/commandFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/completedCommandsFragment"
        android:name="io.dailyunix.CompletedCommandsFragment"
        android:label="Completed commands"
        android:icon="@+id/ic_menu_info_details"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/remainingCommandsFragment"
        android:name="io.dailyunix.RemainingCommandsFragment"
        android:label="Remaining commands"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/commandFragment"
        android:name="io.dailyunix.CommandFragment"
        android:label="Command"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_command" >
        <argument
            android:name="command"
            app:argType="string" />
    </fragment>

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_global_commandFragment"
        app:destination="@id/commandFragment" />
  </navigation>
```

The addition of this attribute seems to have done nothing:

```
    android:icon="@+id/ic_menu_info_details"
```

I haven't had to add any layout for the items in the nav, so I don't know what it's using for this. I don't see any mention of how to do this in the navigation codelab either.

[Edit]

DevMike01 points out that I should use `@drawable/`, not `@+id/` for referring to the icon (duh). But fixing this seems insufficient to fix the issue. Here's a screenshot of the layout inspector.

[image: layout inspector]

[Edit 2]

Looks like this can be done programmatically in the Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
  ...
  navigation.menu.getItem(0).icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_completed)
  navigation.menu.getItem(1).icon = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_remaining)
  ...
}
```

But that's action at a distance and brittle. I'd prefer to do this in the XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I did in fact have another file lying around that I'd forgotten about, `menu/nav.xml`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/completedCommandsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_completed"
    android:title="@string/completed"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/remainingCommandsFragment"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_remaining"
    android:title="@string/remaining"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

I thought that my menu items were being dynamically generated by the navigation component based on my `navigation/nav_graph.xml` file, but they're not. I needed to keep these two files in sync and use the `menu/nav.xml` for the icons. It seems the IDs on the item tags in `menu/nav.xml` need to match the IDs on the fragment tags in `navigation/nav_graph.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Save your icons in drawable folder and change the way you reference it to this `@drawable/ic_menu_info_details`, assuming the name of the icon is `ic_menu_info_details`. `@+id/...` is used to assign an id to a view.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks. This was definitely wrong as it was, but even with it fixed I see the same issue. Will add a screenshot of the layout inspector to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set drawer icons from its menu xml file by adding `android:icon` attribute to the item.

Example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:id="@+id/primary">
        <item
            android:id="@id/home_dest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
            android:title="@string/home" />
        <item
            android:id="@id/deeplink_dest"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_android"
            android:title="@string/deeplink" />
    </group>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings_dest"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />

</menu>
```

Here your res/drawable need has to have the top referenced icons (ic_android, ic_settings, home_dest) which you can grab from android assets

```
( res > RClick > New > Image Assets / Vector Assets)
```

Comment: But I don't have a menu XML file. I have a nav graph XML file instead. Navigation UI looks after generating the menu from the nav graph.